# How do I connect storm crawler to elastic?

Tags: elasticsearch, search, web-crawler, apache-storm

I have storm crawler and elastic in 2 separate servers, how can I connect them so elastic can index storm crawler data? Is there a plugin for this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [repository](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/tree/master/external/elasticsearch)
"Video tutorial" in the description is brilliant